# WifiClientSecure connect returns 0 ( fail ) except for www.google.com which connects

Tags: esp8266

So to wile away the long lockdown and curfew hours I decided to get out a stack of Wemos D1 mini ESP8266 boards and build simple indoor temperature and humidity sensors ( using an SHT30 and feeding the data into Graphite or Influx ). I'm using the WifiClientSecure library but its connect() function returns 0 ( false/fail ) every time I try this except when I connect to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). I've tried connecting to various other servers, both port 80 and 443 but they all fail. I can connect to all of these server absolutely fine from my network so it's not a firewalling issue. The D1 does get an IP and has DNS ( in fact, in my full sketch I'm using NTP with pool.ntp.org and that works fine ).

I've created a simple test ( https://gist.github.com/mkraats/1d1b11691c179793c799fcbb21e5debe ) with just the connect to WiFi and connect() but I still get the same results.

This code:

```
    char servername[]="www.google.com";
  
    int connectval;
    connectval = client.connect(servername, 443 );
    Serial.println("...");
    Serial.println(connectval);
    Serial.println("...");
    delay(12000);

}
```

Works fine while this:

```
void loop() {

    char servername[]="graphite-us-central1.grafana.net";
  
    int connectval;
    connectval = client.connect(servername, 443 );
    Serial.println("...");
    Serial.println(connectval);
    Serial.println("...");
    delay(12000);

}
```

Does not. What stupid mistake am I making that I am not seeing? :-)

Comment: graphite-us-central1.grafana.net does not seem to listen on https port 443

Comment: @SimSon I checked on my PC with curl https://graphite-us-central1.grafana.net:443 . That worked. So I guess, it does serve https on port 443

Comment: No, https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/graphite-us-central1.grafana.net works, so it definitely does listen.

Comment: do you have `All SSL ciphers (most compatible)` selected in Tools menu?

Comment: Yes, that is selected. It also wouldn't explain why plain old HTTP port 80 doesn't work.

Comment: does the site allow unsecure connection?